# Django: Foreign key optional but unique?

Tags: python, sql, django

I have a model (`A`) that has 2 foreign keys: `b` and `c`.

`b` and `c` should unique together **INCLUDING NULL**

therefore `b` and `c` should only be NULL together **ONCE**

However, I am unable to accomplish this in Django. Here is the code I have so far. Any help is appreciated!

-_-

```
class A(models.Model):
  b = models.ForeignKey('B', blank = True, null = True)
  c = models.ForeignKey('C', blank = True, null = True)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = (
      ('b', 'c')
    )
```

This code will produce this unwanted result in the database:

```
+----+------+------+
| id | b_id | c_id |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    2 | 3    |
|  2 |    2 | 77   |
|  3 |    2 | NULL |
|  4 |    2 | NULL |
|  5 | NULL | NULL |
|  6 | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+
```

The first 2 rows can only be inserted once by django. **which is great** :)

However, the remaining rows are duplicate entries for me, and i'd like to restrict this.

**UPDATE**

I've found something that gets the job done, but it seems really hacky..
Any thoughts?

```
class A(models.Model):
  def clean(self):
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

    if not any([self.b, self.c]):
      if Setting.objects.filter(b__isnull = True, c__isnull = True).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Already exists")

    elif self.b and not self.c:
      if Setting.objects.filter(c__isnull = True, b = self.b).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Already exists")

    elif self.c and not self.user:
      if Setting.objects.filter(c = self.c, b__isnull = True).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Already exists")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a better solution out there, but you could do the following:

1. create a new attribute `d` and find a generic way to combine `b_id` and `c_id` (e.g. `str(b_id) + "*" + str(c_id)` and do this automatically on model creation (the signals mechanism might come in handy, here)
2. use `d` as primary_key

This is more a work around then a solution, but it should do the trick.

One more thought: Would it be an option to check whether there is aready an existing instance with "Null"/"Null" on creation / update of your instance? This would not solve your problem on database level, but the logics would work as expected.

Comment: Why not `d` as primary key, or at least with a unique constraint?

Comment: ... So `d` is a `ForeignKey`? I thought it was a computed value based on `b_id` and `c_id`. Now I'm confused.

Comment: one should not type in answers in a hurry... You are right, `d` is a computed value (and of course, not a ForeignKey and therefore there is no d_id). Thanks @MikeDeSimone, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with Django but with the SQL spec itself - NULL is not a value, so it must NOT be taken into account for uniqueness constraints checks.

You can either have a "pseudo-null" B record and a "pseudo-null" C record in your db and make them the defaults (and not allow NULL of course), or have a denormalized field like OBu suggests.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Unique** constraint for **b_id** column. It wont allow the **duplicate  entries**. Even for a_id column, **primary key** can be used. Primary key means the combination of unique key and not null constraints.

Comment: Hey Nagarajan, I've updated my example to help clarify my goal.

Comment: column b can not be unique on its own, but it should be unique together with column c. The issue I'm having is putting this restriction on null entries.

Comment: If it is a unique key means it will allow a single null value for those Column. if u put unique for b_id it will accept one null and c_id will allow one null in the same manner. Do you want to put null fo each IDs in b_id and c_id. If it so thas quite complex.